# How to find the public key in a digital certificate

Tags: rsa, public-key, tls, openssl, certificates

I can see what I think should be the public key in the Details tab for StackOverflow's certificate (see screenshot below).
However, it is 2160 (num of chars (540) multiplied by 4 = 2160) bits long, not 2048 as it specifies.

When I view the certificate details using `openssl` in cmd, I can see a smaller version of the public key which is 514 nibbles * 4 = 2056 bits, which is one byte off 2048.

I noticed the first byte is 00. Is the first byte to be ignored because it's 0?
Why is it displayed in openssl?

If the first byte is to be ignored, does this mean the actual public key starts with `b2` and ends in `af`?

Why does Windows show extra bytes before and after the public key in the Details tab?

I've used Notepad in the screenshot to show the full value of what's in the Details tab.

[image]

**Update:**

I realised the majority of the bytes is the modulus, and the exponent 0x010001 is at the end:

[image]

But what is the `02 03` between the modulus and the exponent?

And what is the `30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00` before the modulus?

Comment: Try pasting the hex in an [ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/)

Comment: Your question is not finding the publickey -- you already found it. Your question is _decoding_ it. As https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3279#section-2.3.1 says it is the DER encoding of ASN.1 structure RSAPublicKey from PKCS1, and as meshcollider says DER is now in X.690, although https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690 is easier to read than the actual ITU-T document, and so is https://letsencrypt.org/docs/a-warm-welcome-to-asn1-and-der/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per X.690, the format begins with `0x30` to denote a sequence.
Next comes the total length. The first byte of the length is `0x82`. Because the highest bit is set here, it means this byte encodes the length *of the length*. In other words, the next 2 bytes encode the actual length. Those bytes are `0x010a`, or 266 bytes.

Now we hit another tag. This time it is `0x02`, meaning an integer. The length starts with `0x82` again, so we know the subsequent 2 bytes encode the length. These are `0x0101`, so the total length of this integer is 257 bytes. These 257 bytes are the ones you highlighted. The reason the extra `0x00` byte is included in the start is because BER integers are signed and represented in 2's complement - if there was no leading null byte, it would be interpreted as a negative number, since the next byte `0xb2` has the highest bit set.

After those 257 bytes for the modulus, we hit another tag: `0x02` again. Another integer. This time the first byte (`0x03`) of the length doesn't have the highest bit set, so the length is simply 3 bytes. These 3 bytes are `0x010001`, or 65537. That's the public exponent.

And that totals 266 bytes, as expected for the whole sequence. It is just those 2 integers.

Comment: I edited the answer to explain why the leading nul byte is there.